# How to configure the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Tags: nginx

I am using the nginx server, on Ruby on Rails, Now problem is how to configure the nginx.conf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please be more specific and tell us what you want it to do?
Maybe you could had used google and gone to the [nginx wiki for this](http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration).
If you can't figure it out, please specify what you cant get working and what it needs to do.